# Destroying condition_variable while waiting

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

First my code to make my explanation more clear:

```
struct Foo {
    std::condition_variable cv;
};
static Foo* foo; // dynamically created object

// Thread1
foo->cv.wait(...);


// Thread2
foo->cv.notify();
delete foo; // thread1 might have not left the wait function yet
```

I am trying to delete a `std::condition_variable` while it is in `wait`. So from my understanding, I have to notify it first to make it leave it's waiting for routine, and then I can delete it. But after calling `notify*` I can't delete it right away, because it might still be in wait because it needs a few cycles. What is a common way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`?

Comment: Just have `std::shared_ptr` in both threads

Comment: Since it looks like you only use `foo` once, this might be a use case for the far simpler `std::promise`/`std::future`.

Comment: Because of the existing code I am working on I can't use std::shared_ptr at the moment

Comment: Then, how about using some other implementation of shared pointer?

Comment: @DanielStephens Then it sounds like maybe Thread1 should be responsible for `foo` and not Thread2.

Comment: @DanielStephens How come you can use [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) but not [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)? They were introduced together at C++11...

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist I am just fixing a bug and can't change more than necessary.. historically grown code :-)

Comment: @DanielStephens if you truly want a real fix free of race conditions you need to change the design. at the very least each thread needs a `shared_ptr` to `foo`

Comment: If you have to ask, "will this funny-looking trick work?," then you potentially are forcing anybody else who reads your code to ask the same question. If you use too many tricky tricks in your code, you may find that other developers don't like to collaborate with you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can delete it right away.

Quote from C++ standard:

> `~ condition_variable();`
>
> *Requires*: There shall be no thread blocked on `*this`. [Note: That is,
>   all threads shall have been notified; they may subsequently block on
>   the lock specified in the `wait`. This relaxes the usual rules, which
>   would have required all `wait` calls to happen before destruction. **Only
>   the notification to unblock the `wait` must happen before destruction.**

Basically `wait` functions are required to perform locking and waiting atomically:

> The execution of `notify_one` and `notify_all` shall be atomic. The execution 
>   of `wait`, `wait_for`, and `wait_until` shall be performed in three atomic parts:
>
> 1. the release of the mutex and entry into the waiting state;
> 2. the unblocking of the `wait`; and
> 3. the reacquisition of the lock.

Once `notify` wakes a thread, it should be considered "unblocked" and should contest the mutex.

---

There are similar guarantees about `std::mutex`: threads are not required to leave `unlock` before mutex is destroyed.

Quote from C++ standard:

> The implementation shall provide `lock` and `unlock` operations, as
>   described below. For purposes of determining the existence of a data
>   race, these behave as atomic operations. The `lock` and `unlock`
>   operations on a single mutex shall appear to occur in a single total
>   order.

Later:

> Note: After a thread A has called `unlock()`, releasing a mutex, it is
>   possible for another thread B to lock the same mutex, observe that it
>   is no longer in use, unlock it, and **destroy it, before thread A
>   appears to have returned from its `unlock` call**.

Such guarantees are required to avoid issues like [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/575460/), when mutex inside an object is used to protect object reference counter.

---

Note that this does not guarantee that your implementation has no bugs in this regard. In the past glibc had multiple bugs related to the destruction of synchronization objects, in particular `pthread_mutex_unlock` was [accessing mutex before returning](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13690).

Comment: There was a request to clarify this behavior for `pthread_cond_t` and it was confirmed to be the same. I cannot find the link at the moment. But C++ primities should have similar guarantees as POSIX primitives when it comes to destruction.

Comment: i did not realize this. +1, but please provide a link too.

Comment: @BradAllred [Here](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=609). I will add this to the answer soon. Also [this](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13165) bug in glibc.

Comment: And the original clatification that was added to C++ is [here](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2190)

Answer (score 1):

One easy fix: move `delete foo` into thread 1 after `foo->cv.wait(...);`.

A better fix would be to change the design to work with `std::shared_ptr`, no manual `delete` invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for C++17 (C++11 needs adaptation): **notify everybody that we are deleting current instance and make the destructor to wait**

Two things to do:

1. Give to the wait predicate a possibility to exit before object is really deleted
2. Make the destructor to resync with the lock to make it wait everything is finished (you must be sure all waiting methods are checking the `deleting` at beginning)

***Note:*** if you have a thread inside this class waiting on the `condition_variable`, it might be better to `join()` the thread after notification instead of using the resynchronization lock (see comment in the code)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>

using namespace std;

chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime;

struct Foo
{
    condition_variable cond;
    mutex mutex1;
    shared_mutex mutexSafe;

    bool deleting = false;

    ~Foo()
    {
        deleting = true;
        cond.notify_all();
        
        // Will make the destructor to wait all the opened shared_lock are released
        unique_lock l(mutexSafe);
    }

    void waitOnThing(const string& name)
    {
        // Shared lock to make possible several threads are using the method at the same time
        shared_lock lSafe(mutexSafe);

        cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime).count()
            << " Thread " << name << " -> waitOnThing()" << endl;

        unique_lock l(mutex1);
        cond.wait(l, [&]()
            {
                if (deleting)
                {
                    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000)); // Slow down exit process to show destructor is waiting
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });

        cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime).count()
            << " Thread " << name << " unlocked" << endl;
    }
};



int main()
{
    startTime = chrono::system_clock::now();
    Foo* foo = new Foo();
    
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime).count()
        << " Starting" << endl;

    thread t1([&]() { foo->waitOnThing("t1"); });
    thread t2([&]() { foo->waitOnThing("t2"); });
    thread t3([&]() { foo->waitOnThing("t3"); });

    // Wait a bit to be sure thread started and is waiting
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
    
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime).count()
        << " Deleting foo..." << endl;
    delete foo;

    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime).count()
        << " Foo deleted" << endl;

    // Avoid demo to crash
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

Result:

```
0 Starting
4 Thread t2 -> waitOnThing()
4 Thread t1 -> waitOnThing()
4 Thread t3 -> waitOnThing()
100 Deleting foo...
1100 Thread t1 unlocked
2100 Thread t2 unlocked
3100 Thread t3 unlocked
3100 Foo deleted
```

**C++11 :**

Class `shared_mutex` is available only since C++17, if you are using C++11 you can do the same by using a regular `unique_lock`
and making a `vector` of `mutex` (one instance per call to the waiting method) and try to lock all of them in the destructor.

*Example (not tested):*

```cpp
vector<shared_ptr<mutex>> mutexesSafe;

~Foo()
{
    // ...
    
    for(const auto& m : mutexesSafe)
    {
        unique_lock l(m);
    }
}
void waitOnThing(const string& name)
{
    auto m = make_shared<mutex>();
    mutexesSafe.push_back(m);
    unique_lock lSafe(*m);
    
    //...
}
```